# How to querying on build sisense elastic cube?

Tags: elastic-stack, bi-tool, sisense

I am new in Sisense tool. I have created elastic cube in Sisense and built this cube successfully. Now the elastic cube result does not match the source database result.

So is there any way to execute a query on Sisense built elastic cube to validate the cube data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a web based tool that lets you write sql against your cube. It was called SqlRunner, and is now SqlEditor

https://developers.sisense.com/display/API2/SQL+Runner

An example command line which I've tested is

[http://localhost:8081/app/sqleditor#/datasource=YourCubeNameHere&query=select%20*%20from%20%5Bdbo.Customer%5D%20&format=csv](http://akd-dbsandbox:8081/app/sqleditor#/datasource=UV_PAcket%20History&query=select%20*%20from%20%5Bdbo.Customer%5D%20&format=csv)

Note that outputs the results as CSV, which you can then cut/paste to Excel

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It's very helpful. Just one more help like how can I execute join query over here in SQL runner? I tried but it gives me an error.

Comment: Can you share the sql and the error please - open a new question maybe?

Comment: Just take sample query from top 10 records from any table. Then it shows error like Query could not be compiled.\r\nFound 'TOP' but '<Expression>' expected.

Comment: Top isn't supported - annoying but that's life

Comment: Ok no worry.Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: TOP is't supported but limit is - different syntax
select * from blah limit 10;